# Is time complexity of following program is O(1)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This is the code to find if a number is sparse or not

```
def isSparse(n):
   if n & (n >> 1):
      return False
   return True
```

is the time complexity **O(1)**?

Comment: What programming language is that? I know many programming languages, I've even made my own programming language ( https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly ), and I can't guess which programming language that would be.

Comment: @FlatAssembler it's Python. If you haven't tried it before, you are in for a good time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. It scales linearly with the number of digits.

This is **O(log N)**

Check out this simple code

````
>>> import timeit
>>> def isSparse(n):
...    if n & (n >> 1):
...       return False
...    return True
... 
>>> x_1000="isSparse({})".format(10**1000)
>>> x_10000="isSparse({})".format(10**10000)
>>> x_100000="isSparse({})".format(10**100000)
>>> timeit.timeit(x_1000, globals=globals())
0.38640813998063095
>>> timeit.timeit(x_10000, globals=globals())
2.778634059999604
>>> timeit.timeit(x_100000, globals=globals())
26.778618280019145```
````

Answer (score 1):

No, the complexity is not **O(1)**:

- The function uses a simple expression and a single test. All of these operate in constant time for small values of `n`, so the complexity should be **O(1)**. This works for reasonably small values of `n`, typically 32-bit long.
- python supports arbitrary large integer values for `n`, up to available memory. For very large numbers, the `>> 1` and the `&` operations take time proportional to the number of memory words needed to represent `n`. This means a time complexity of **O(log(n))** for extremely large values of `n`.

In python, the complexity of function `isSparse` is **O(1)** if `n` is
a regular 32-bit `int` and increases to **O(log(n))** for extremely large `n`.

Here is a test to demonstrate this result:

```py
import timeit

def isSparse(n):
   if n & (n >> 1):
      return False
   else:
      return True

def test():
   # measure timing overhead
   clock = timeit.default_timer
   overhead = 1e10
   for _ in range(100):
      t = clock()
      t = clock() - t
      if overhead > t: overhead = t

   for i in range(24):
      p = 2 ** i - 1
      x = 2 ** p
      rep = 10
      tt = 1e10
      for _ in range(rep):
         t = clock()
         for _ in range(100):
            v = isSparse(x)
         t = clock() - t
         if tt > t: tt = t
      t = (tt - overhead) / rep
      print("isSparse(2**%d): %s, %.3fus, t/log(n)=%.3fns" %
            (p, v, t * 1e6, t / (p|1) * 1e9))

test()
```

Output:

```
isSparse(2**0): True, 2.194us, t/log(n)=2194.406ns
isSparse(2**1): True, 3.953us, t/log(n)=3953.301ns
isSparse(2**3): True, 4.015us, t/log(n)=1338.334ns
isSparse(2**7): True, 4.319us, t/log(n)=617.015ns
isSparse(2**15): True, 4.275us, t/log(n)=285.000ns
isSparse(2**31): True, 4.757us, t/log(n)=153.455ns
isSparse(2**63): True, 3.864us, t/log(n)=61.341ns
isSparse(2**127): True, 4.112us, t/log(n)=32.378ns
isSparse(2**255): True, 4.069us, t/log(n)=15.956ns
isSparse(2**511): True, 5.492us, t/log(n)=10.747ns
isSparse(2**1023): True, 6.589us, t/log(n)=6.441ns
isSparse(2**2047): True, 7.442us, t/log(n)=3.635ns
isSparse(2**4095): True, 15.696us, t/log(n)=3.833ns
isSparse(2**8191): True, 16.141us, t/log(n)=1.971ns
isSparse(2**16383): True, 25.743us, t/log(n)=1.571ns
isSparse(2**32767): True, 35.646us, t/log(n)=1.088ns
isSparse(2**65535): True, 105.032us, t/log(n)=1.603ns
isSparse(2**131071): True, 142.656us, t/log(n)=1.088ns
isSparse(2**262143): True, 268.022us, t/log(n)=1.022ns
isSparse(2**524287): True, 623.609us, t/log(n)=1.189ns
isSparse(2**1048575): True, 1073.612us, t/log(n)=1.024ns
isSparse(2**2097151): True, 2112.068us, t/log(n)=1.007ns
isSparse(2**4194303): True, 4423.266us, t/log(n)=1.055ns
isSparse(2**8388607): True, 9155.862us, t/log(n)=1.091ns
```

Comment: This answer does a great job of digging deeper. For small n, the complexity *is* constant.